# Logistic Regression using Tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a multi-class logistic regression using TensorFlow 2.0 and I've wrote the code which I think is correct but it's not giving out good results. My accuracy is literally 0.1% and even loss is not decreasing. I was hoping someone could help me out here.

This is the code I've written so far. Please points out what am I doing wrong here that I need to improve so the my model works. Thanks you!

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train/255., x_test/255.

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.15)
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train, shape=(-1, 784))
x_test  = tf.reshape(x_test, shape=(-1, 784))

weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(784, 10), dtype=tf.float64))
biases  = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(10,), dtype=tf.float64))

def logistic_regression(x):
    lr = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights), biases)
    return tf.nn.sigmoid(lr)

def cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.one_hot(y_true, 10)
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.int32)
    preds = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), dtype=tf.int32)
    preds = tf.equal(y_true, preds)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(preds, dtype=tf.float32))

def grad(x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = logistic_regression(x)
        loss_val = cross_entropy(y, y_pred)
    return tape.gradient(loss_val, [weights, biases])

epochs = 1000
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 128

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(x_train.shape[0]).batch(batch_size)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)

for epoch, (batch_xs, batch_ys) in enumerate(dataset.take(epochs), 1):
    gradients = grad(batch_xs, batch_ys)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [weights, biases]))

    y_pred = logistic_regression(batch_xs)
    loss = cross_entropy(batch_ys, y_pred)
    acc = accuracy(batch_ys, y_pred)
    print("step: %i, loss: %f, accuracy: %f" % (epoch, loss, acc))

    step: 1000, loss: 2.458979, accuracy: 0.101562
```

Comment: Have you tried just using simple tf.keras api?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The model is not converging, and the problem seems to be that you are doing a sigmoid activation directly followed by `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. In the documentation for the `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` it says:

> WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a `softmax` on `logits` internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of `softmax`, as it will produce incorrect results.

Hence no softmax, sigmoid, relu, tanh or any other activations should be done on the output of the previous layer before passed to `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`. 
For more in depth description of when to use sigmoid or softmax output activation, see [here](https://dev.to/rosejcday/learning-the-differences-between-softmax-and-sigmoid-for-image-classification--59c).

Therfore by replacing `return tf.nn.sigmoid(lr)` with just `return lr` in the `logistic_regression` function, the model is converging.

Below is a working example of your code with the above fix. I also changed the variable name `epochs` to `n_batches` as your training loop actually goes through 1000 batches not 1000 epochs (i also bumped it up to 10000 as there was sign of more iterations needed).

```py
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train/255., x_test/255.

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.15)
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train, shape=(-1, 784))
x_test  = tf.reshape(x_test, shape=(-1, 784))

weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(784, 10), dtype=tf.float64))
biases  = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(10,), dtype=tf.float64))

def logistic_regression(x):
    lr = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights), biases)
    #return tf.nn.sigmoid(lr)
    return lr


def cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.one_hot(y_true, 10)
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.int32)
    preds = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), dtype=tf.int32)
    preds = tf.equal(y_true, preds)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(preds, dtype=tf.float32))

def grad(x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = logistic_regression(x)
        loss_val = cross_entropy(y, y_pred)
    return tape.gradient(loss_val, [weights, biases])

n_batches = 10000
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 128

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(x_train.shape[0]).batch(batch_size)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)

for batch_numb, (batch_xs, batch_ys) in enumerate(dataset.take(n_batches), 1):
    gradients = grad(batch_xs, batch_ys)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [weights, biases]))

    y_pred = logistic_regression(batch_xs)
    loss = cross_entropy(batch_ys, y_pred)
    acc = accuracy(batch_ys, y_pred)
    print("Batch number: %i, loss: %f, accuracy: %f" % (batch_numb, loss, acc))

(removed printouts)
>> Batch number: 1000, loss: 2.868473, accuracy: 0.546875
(removed printouts)
>> Batch number: 10000, loss: 1.482554, accuracy: 0.718750
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I use sigmoid loss function here rather than softmax cross entropy?

Comment: @user214 for the fashion_mnist dataset, you have one, but only one correct class for each image. Therefor softmax, or the loss "tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits" is correct. If you one the other hand had a dataset where you could have multiple correct labels in each image you should use sigmoid or just change the loss to "tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits"  (for more information see [multiclass vs multilabel problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11859/what-is-the-difference-between-multiclass-and-multilabel-problem/11866)).

Comment: @KrisR89 sorry sir, how can you add tensorboard visualization to this answer? I get lost in version 1.x

Comment: @LuisFelipe I suggest you have a look at [tensorboard get started documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started), they show how to visualize stats using tensorboard with`model.fit()` and  custom training like the answer above.