# Binary Logistic Regression - do we need to one_hot encode label?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, label, one-hot-encoding

I have a logistic regression model which I created referring this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907971/logistic-regression-using-tensorflow-2-0)

The label is a Boolean value (0 or 1 as values).

Do we need to do one_hot encode the label in this case?

The reason for asking : I use the below function for finding the cross_entropy and loss is always coming as zero.

```
def cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.one_hot([y_true.numpy()], 2)
    print(y_pred)
    print(y_true)
    loss_row = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)
    print('Loss')
    print(loss_row)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss_row)
```

EDIT :- The gradient is giving [None,None] as return value (for following code).

```
def grad(x, y):
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = logistic_regression(x)
    loss_val = cross_entropy(y, y_pred)       
return tape.gradient(loss_val, [w, b])
```

Examples values

loss_val => tf.Tensor(307700.47, shape=(), dtype=float32)

w => tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(171, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.7456649 ], [-0.35111237],[-0.6848465 ],[ 0.22605407]]

b => tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.1982833], dtype=float32)

Comment: In case of binary logistic regression, you don't required one_hot encoding. It generally used in multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: In the reference, fashion_mnist data set has 10 labels (i.e 0-9) hence it required one_hot encoding where as in your case it has only two labels (ex: Yes :1 or No : 0 or vice versa) so it doesn't required one_hot encoding.

Answer (score 1):

In case of binary logistic regression, you don't required one_hot encoding. It generally used in multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: But when I do that "sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits" is returning zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing ordinary (binary) logistic regression (with 0/1 labels), then use the loss function [tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits).

If you are doing multiclass logistic regression (a.k.a softmax regression or multinomial logistic regission), then you have two choices:

1. Define your labels in 1-hot format (e.g. `[1, 0, 0]`, `[0, 1, 0]`, ...) and use the loss function [tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)
2. Define your labels as single integers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, ...) and use the loss function [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits)

For the latter two, you can find more information in this StackOverflow question:

[What's the difference between sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits and softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312421/whats-the-difference-between-sparse-softmax-cross-entropy-with-logits-and-softm)

Comment: I am getting zero value for  tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(). could you please tell me what can be the issue.

Comment: It's possible your data is not in the form that you expect it to be. Print out their shapes, types, and values and make sure they're what the function call expects. Compare shapes, types, and values with the examples in the TensorFlow tutorial.

Comment: thank you. now the loss function is working with tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(), Now the return tape.gradient(loss_val, [w, b]) is returning [None, None]

Comment: When we use  tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(), the loss will be a tensor with single value in it ( tf.Tensor(636812.56, shape=(), dtype=float32) ). And when we get the gradient of the loss value with respect to weights and b, it is always zero.

Comment: Follow the examples here: https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/02_logistic_regression.py  In fact, this github repo has a lot of good TensorFlow examples.

Comment: Also here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/2017/lectures/notes_03.pdf

Comment: the examples are using tensor 1.0. (and I am trying in 2.0). I have a question, is there a format for the inputs of gradient function?

Comment: What "gradient function" are you referring to?

Comment: If you see the link I have specified. I am referring to the "return" value of "with tf.GradientTape() as tape:"

Comment: I'm not familiar with that API. Sorry.